# How to detect the compile-time ./configure options of apache 1.3?

Tags: apache, compilation, configure

I have an old apache 1.3 instalation. I know it was compiled from source, I have source tarbal, but I do not have saved ./configure flags.

I need to recompile this apache with exacly same confiugre flags, and with EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DBIG_SECURITY_HOLE" enabled for debugging.

Do you know how to determine ./congigure flags from installed apache? I need something similar to the output of php-config.

Thanks, in advance
SWilk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does httpd -V tell anything on 1.3? (it does tell this on 2.x) but don't have any 1.3 installations available so I could check this.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. 
It only displays a list of modules compiled: (like -D MODULE_NAME="/path/..."), the server version, build date, and "Module Magic Number", nothing more.

Comment: I think there is no way to figure this out, other than trial and error... If the binary was not stripped, looking at the symblols might give you some hints.

Why do you need to recompile the exact same configure flags? Can't you just recompile with the same modules etc and replace the running installation with that?

Comment: Sorry for no response. I wanted to recompile the apache with enabled debugging, but I wanted to create a binary as close to the original version as possible, cause I needed to find a reason of a segfault. 

Fortunatelly we have managed to track down the segfault with xdebug tracing feature, so no more need to do that.

Thank you for your time and attention.